# Swift Dictionary API "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"type\", intValue: nil) (\"type\").", underlyingError: nil))

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, swift5

I am running into a error showing that there is no value for "type" from the API I'm trying to grab from. Ive tried looking through other posts revolving around this but can't find anything that works for me without causing a different issue to come up.

The full error I'm getting is "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: "type", intValue: nil) ("type").", underlyingError: nil))

The API I'm trying to grab from is: https://github.com/ToontownRewritten/api-doc/blob/master/invasions.md

```
import UIKit

struct InvasionList: Decodable {
    let type: String
    let asOf: Int?
    let progress: String?
    
    
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let jsonUrlString = "https://www.toontownrewritten.com/api/invasions"
        guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else { return }
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
            
            guard let data = data else {return }
            
            do {
                let invasions = try JSONDecoder().decode(InvasionList.self, from: data)
                print(invasions.type)
            
            
            } catch let err {
                print(err)
            }
            
            
            }.resume()
        
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `InvasionList` doesn't actually match the structure of the JSON that you're trying to decode. It matches one small part of it, but you need to decode the entire thing. This includes the outermost wrapper (the part with `lastUpdated` and the dynamic keys for each "invasion").

Here's a working example:

```
let jsonData = """
   {"lastUpdated":1624230138,"invasions":{"Gulp Gulch":{"asOf":1624230127,"type":"Robber Baron","progress":"3797/7340"},"Splashport":{"asOf":1624230129,"type":"Ambulance Chaser","progress":"2551/8000"},"Kaboom Cliffs":{"asOf":1624230131,"type":"Money Bags","progress":"5504/6000"},"Boingbury":{"asOf":1624230132,"type":"Tightwad","progress":"4741/8580"}},"error":null}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

struct InvasionWrapper: Decodable {
    let lastUpdated : Int
    let invasions : [String:Invasion]
}

struct Invasion: Decodable {
    let type: String
    let asOf: Int?
    let progress: String?
}

do {
    let list = try JSONDecoder().decode(InvasionWrapper.self, from: jsonData)
    print(list)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: So I implemented this and now it doesn't show a error but it's just printing out the predefined output that you put at the top with 'jsonData = "" '

Comment: If you're really printing the result of the decoding, it's not printing exactly that -- it's printing the Swift version of it encoded into structs. What are you expecting to see?

Comment: I'm trying to print out the updated info from the API. I know it will be in the same format as we put but the data is old and changing so I'm trying to pull it again from the API

Comment: I gave an example where it just uses that one string. The important part is adding the `InvasionWrapper` and changing the `JSONDecoder` line, which you can incorporate into your code in the `URLSession` -- do you know how to do that or would you like me to show you?

Comment: Ah I see what you mean, I've gotten it. How can I print out only a part of it like if I wanted the "type" or just one invasion.

Comment: If you wanted one invasion, you'd probably want to know the key of it first. So, you'd do something like `list.invasions["Gulp Gulch"]` or `list.invasions["Gulp Gulch"].type`. `list.invasions` is what's called a `Dictionary` in Swift. Might be good to do some research on the different ways to access dictionary elements in Swift.

Comment: The Gulp Gulch (Server name) part changes to a different server name (There's about 20). The API only shows the active invasions with the servers that the invasion is active in.

Would I just need to make one for every server and check if its in the output before printing it?

Comment: It depends what you want to do. You could hard code in all of the possibilities or you can look up how to list the keys of a Dictionary dynamically.

Comment: Alright thanks I got that working, I will lookup and watch some vids on the stuff you suggested. If there's anything in particular you think would be good to checkout I would really appreciate it.

Otherwise thanks for the help and for fixing this for me